# модуль zoneinfo python

Tags: python, zoneinfo

Почему при запуске этого кода выдает ошибку в третьей строке.

```
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
moskow = ZoneInfo("Europe/Moscow")
t1 = datetime(2023,5,2,12,30,0, tzinfo=moskow)
print(t1)
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\python\python разработчік\9_1_11_1.py", line 3, in <module>
    moskow = ZoneInfo("Europe/Moscow")
  File "C:\Users\Vasily\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\zoneinfo\_common.py", 
line 24, in load_tzdata
    raise ZoneInfoNotFoundError(f"No time zone found with key {key}")
zoneinfo._common.ZoneInfoNotFoundError: 'No time zone found with key Europe/Moscow'
```

Comment: Потому что Windows не содержит нужной базы часовых поясов и нужно установить её вручную https://pypi.org/project/tzdata/